# One comma or two? I have since been

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

Which of the following is correct?

*Context:* I left AMD in early 2008.

> I have, since, been the CTO of a large software firm near Oregon.

or is it

> I have since, been the CTO of a large software firm near Oregon.

Comment: Both sound odd to me. I prefer no comma at all. But if I have to choose between the two, I will choose the first one.

Comment: Neither makes sense. Can you give some wider context to fit this sentence into.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I completed the sentence; and added context.

Comment: The second one is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inserting *since* into the verb phrase, I don't seen that either of your examples could be used unless you are writing dialog.

Comment: Wihout the commas, you could say *I was made redundant last year. I have since been looking for a job.* OP either did not make clear or does not understand that the sentence cannot stand on its own.

Comment: @Foxish "I have since been doing XYZ" or "I have been doing XYZ since" or "Since, I have been doing XYZ" — If you're using 'since' mid-sentence though, the use of a comma would give the sentence an odd flow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

> "I left EMD in early 2008.  Since then I have been the CTO of a large software firm near Oregon."

Or,

> "I left EMD in early 2008, and since then I have been the CTO . . .."

Or,

> "I left EMD in early 2008 and became the CTO . . .."

Or,

> "After leaving EMD in early 2008 I became the CTO . . .."

Or,

> "In early 2008 I left EMD and became the CTO . . .."

Or,

> "I became the CTO of a large software firm near Oregon after having left EMD in early 2008."

There are any number of possibilities here, but your first two examples sound awfully stilted to me; I suggest you eighty-six them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, neither.   You *can* say *I have since been CTO* (no commas, any more than in *I was yesterday looking*; it sounds about as stilted); or you can say *I have, since then, been CTO...*. Logically , *I have, since, been CTO...* would make sense, but in fact it sounds to me so unidiomatic as to be actually wrong. A single comma would be painfully jarring, and unjustifiable.

Your amended question also does not show you are aware that *I left AMD in early 2008* must be the immediately preceding sentence. In the circumstances it would probably be safer to avoid the construction altogether; any of rhetorician's alternatives would be better.